# Downloading Multiple Files via SFTP using Java

Tags: java, file, sftp, jsch

I am new to java and I am trying to write a script that will pull multiple files from various SFTP sites daily.

I have code below that will pull 1 file from 1 site and it works,  however I am struggling to find how to modify my code so that it will download multiple files.  So for example all the files in the remote directory, or only certain files containing certain letters

Can you advise me on this please?

code:-

```
package package1;  

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;  
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.OutputStream;  
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;  
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;  
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;  
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;  



public class SFTPpullsshkeys {  
public SFTPpullsshkeys() {  
                          }

public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String SFTPHOST = "IP";  
        int    SFTPPORT = 22;  
        String SFTPUSER = "Username";  
        String passphrase = "passphrase";  
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "remote directory";    
        String prikeyfile = "C:\\Open SSH Key.ppk";


        Session     session     = null;  
        Channel     channel     = null;  
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;  

try{  
        JSch jsch = new JSch();  
        jsch.addIdentity(prikeyfile, passphrase);
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);  
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 
        session.connect();  
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");  
        channel.connect();  
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;  
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(channelSftp.get("file.csv"));  
        File newFile = new File("C:\\file.csv"); 
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(newFile);  
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);  
        int readCount;  

while
        ( (readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
        System.out.println("Writing files to disk: " );  
        bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);  
        }  
        bis.close();  
        bos.close();  
        }catch(Exception ex){  
        ex.printStackTrace();  

        }  

    }      

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get a directory listing and iterate through it:

```
    try {
            channel.connect();
            logger.info("shell channel connected....");             
        } catch(JSchException e) {
            logger.warning("Could not connect: " + e.toString());
            logStreamForEmail.close();

        }

        if (!channel.isConnected()) {

            // Close the log stream for email.  This causes it to write all output to the Byte Array Output Stream, which we can dump into email Body Texts
            logStreamForEmail.close();

            // Send warning email, could not connect
            new SendEmail(warningEmailAddress, "SFTP Warning: Could not connect to host", baosForEmail.toString());
        } else {   
            try {   
                ChannelSftp c = (ChannelSftp) channel;   
                c.lcd(localDir);
                logger.info("lcd " + c.lpwd());

                // Get a listing of the remote directory
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = c.ls("."); 
                logger.info("ls .");

                // iterate through objects in list, identifying specific file names
                for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry oListItem : list) {
                    // output each item from directory listing for logs
                    logger.info(oListItem.toString()); 

                    // If it is a file (not a directory)
                    if (!oListItem.getAttrs().isDir()) {
                        // Grab the remote file ([remote filename], [local path/filename to write file to])

                        logger.info("get " + oListItem.getFilename());
                        c.get(oListItem.getFilename(), oListItem.getFilename());  // while testing, disable this or all of your test files will be grabbed

                        grabCount++; 

                        // Delete remote file
                        //c.rm(oListItem.getFilename());  // Note for SFTP grabs from this remote host, deleting the file is unnecessary, 
                                                          //   as their system automatically moves an item to the 'downloaded' subfolder
                                                          //   after it has been grabbed.  For other target hosts, un comment this line to remove any downloaded files from the inbox.
                    }
                }

                // Report files grabbed to log
                if (grabCount == 0) { 
                    logger.info("Found no new files to grab.");
                } else {
                    logger.info("Retrieved " + grabCount + " new files.");
                }                           
            } catch(SftpException e) {
                logger.warning(e.toString());
            } finally {
                // disconnect session.  If this is not done, the job will hang and leave log files locked
                session.disconnect();
                logger.info("Session Closed");
            }
```

You can replace all 'logger.warning' and 'logger.info' with System.out.println if you are not using a logger.

Answer (score 2):

```
Download & Decrypt file from SFTP using JSCH

/**
 * The class to download the files from SFTP server.
 */
package com.test.service;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

/**
 * @author varunvikramsingh@gmail.com
 * 
 */
@Service
public class DownloadFileServiceJschImpl implements DownloadFileService {
    @Value("${sftpServer}")
    String sftpServer;

    @Value("${sftpUsername}")
    String sftpUsername;

    @Value("${sftpPassword}")
    String sftpPassword;

    @Value("${sftpPort}")
    String sftpPort;

    @Value("${decryptPrivateKey}")
    String DecryptKeyKey;

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public void downloadFile(String ccoid, String reportType, String url, String filename, OutputStream outStream,
            byte[] decryptKeyFromSOA) throws SftpException {

            try {

            // SFTP HOST DETAILS
            String ftpHostSFTP = sftpServer;
            // SFTP PORT NUMBER
            String ftpPortSFTP = sftpPort;
            int parsePort = Integer.parseInt(ftpPortSFTP);
            // SFTP USER NAME
            String ftpUserNameSFTP = sftpUsername.trim();
            // SFTP PASSWORD
            String ftpPasswordSFTP = sftpPassword;
            // SFTP REMOTE DIRECTORY
            String ftpRemoteDirectory = "/data";


            // First Create a JSch session
            logger.info("Creating session with SFTP.");
            // JAVA SECURE CHANNEL API for connecting to the service of via SSH22
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = null;
            Channel channel = null;
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = null;

            logger.info("Trying to Connect to SFTP Server : "+sftpServer);
            logger.info("SFTP Server userName : "+sftpUsername);
            logger.info("SFTP Server sftPort: "+sftpPort);
            logger.info("SFTP Server password: "+sftpPassword);
            session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserNameSFTP, ftpHostSFTP, parsePort);
            //session = jsch.getSession(sftpUsername, sftpServer, sftpPort);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(ftpPasswordSFTP);
            //session.setPassword(sftpPassword);
            session.connect();

            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            sftpChannel.cd("/");
            sftpChannel.cd("/data/");

            logger.info("Current Directory for user is : "+ sftpChannel.pwd());
            logger.info("User is trying to download file :"+filename);

            String newFileName = filename+".enc";

            logger.info("Portal added .enc as suffix to filename, fileName now is :"+newFileName);

            // ==============Decrypt SOA key=================
            byte[] decryptedSOAKeyArray = decrypt(decryptKeyFromSOA,readSecurityKey());
            String soaDecryptedKey = new String(decryptedSOAKeyArray);

            logger.info("Private Key Received from SOA :"+soaDecryptedKey);

            logger.info("Reading the file from SFTP server");

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sftpChannel.get(newFileName));  
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outStream);

            logger.info("Decrypting the file received from SFTP");

            // Decrypt the file
            decrypt(bis, bos, decryptedSOAKeyArray);

            logger.info("File Successfully Downloaded");

            outStream.close();
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();

            logger.info("All connections successfully closed");

        }
        catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;
    private byte[] readSecurityKey() {

        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        byte[] publicKey = null;

        String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/conf");
        String publicKeyfilename = path + "\\PublicKey.txt";

        logger.info("Reading security Key from file :"+publicKeyfilename);

        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(publicKeyfilename);
            publicKey = getByteArrayFromFile(is);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            logger.info("Exception in reading security key "+ioe);
        }
        finally {
            if (null != in) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    /*
                     * Eating this exception since it occurred while closing the input stream.
                     */
                }
            }

        } // end of finally
        return publicKey;
    }

    public static void invokeDecryptFile(String encFilename,String decFilename,byte[] password){
        try{
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(encFilename));
        BufferedOutputStream decout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(decFilename));
        decrypt(is, decout, password);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static byte[] getByteArrayFromFile(InputStream is) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int buf_size = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buf_size];
            int len = 0;
            while (-1 != (len = is.read(buffer, 0, buf_size))) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            byte[] fileContent = out.toByteArray();
            is.close();
            return fileContent;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherTextBytes, byte[] password) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(cipherTextBytes);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        decrypt(bis, bos, password);        
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out, byte[] password) throws Exception{
        final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
        final String transformation="AES/CFB8/NoPadding";
        final int CACHE_SIZE = 64*1024;
        final int IV_LENGTH=16;
        byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
        in.read(iv);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation); 
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password, ALGORITHM);
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        in = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
        byte[] buf = new byte[CACHE_SIZE];
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        out.close();
    }

    // @Override
    // public void downloadFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    // try {
    // int i = 0;
    // byte[] bytesIn = new byte[1024];
    //
    // /*
    // * Loop through the entire file writing bytes.
    // */
    // while ((i = in.read(bytesIn)) >= 0) {
    // out.write(bytesIn, 0, i);
    // }
    //
    // out.close();
    // in.close();
    // }
    // catch(Exception e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // }
    //
    // }


}
```